# Report portal None request failed

Tags: python, github, reportportal

I am trying to reporting result to report portal .

```
robot --listener robotframework_reportportal.listener -v RP_ENDPOINT:"https://XXXXX" -v RP_PROJECT:"TEST" -v RP_UUID:"sfjajf_kl" -v RP_LAUNCH:"xxxx" output.xml
```

Getting issue like below:

> Report portal None request failed

What can be the solution?